# Android Studio- ClassCastException error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite, serializable

I'd like to quickly mention this is a homework assignment, but I'm only looking for direction. My professor has not applied SQLite before, so he's unsure what to do. The class is doing SharedPreference (which I couldn't get), but this was another option to use for storing data for a To-Do List.

Now when I go to hit a button to "Add" a task under the AddDo class, it throws the following error(s):

> ```
>               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{net.example.name.dotoday/net.name.example.dotoday.AddDo}: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.example.name.dotoday.AddDo cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
> ```

EDIT: Here's the class for the actual button. This is where my main task list will reside, as the XML is ready for data and has a button for adding a new task.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Button addMainTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addMainTask);

    addMainTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //This is being flagged as of now because the class type IS not Activity, but serializable.
            startActivity(new Intent(main.this, AddDo.class));

        }
    });
```

This is my class meant for adding a task (this is in early stages):

```
    package net.example.name.dotoday;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AddDo implements Serializable {

    //This is what will be transferred to the actual DB when I make a task.
    public String doParentID, doTaskTitle, doStatus, doDueDate, doCompletedTask, doCalculatedProgress = "";

}
```

This is my DBHandler:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import net.example.name.dotoday.AddDo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DbHelper";

    // Database Info
    private static final String TheDB = "TheDB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    //DB Table Names
    private static final String TABLE_ParentTask = "ParentTask";
    private static final String TABLE_SubTask = "SubTask";


    //ParentTask Table Columns
    private static final String parentIDColumn = "_parentID";
    private static final String taskTitleColumn = "_taskTitle";
    private static final String statusColumn = "_status";
    private static final String dueDateColumn = "_dueDate";
    private static final String completedColumn = "_completedTask"; //When completion is 100%
    private static final String calculatedProgressColumn = "_calculatedProgress"; //LONG VALUE WHEN CONVERTED.

    //SubTask Table Columns
    private static final String foreignkeyColumn = "_foreignkey";
    private static final String childIDColumn = "_childID";
    private static final String subTaskDescColumn = "_subTaskDesc";
    private static final String subCompletedColumn = "_subCompleted"; // BOOL for individual tasks -- may not be implemented


    /*  -- Here comes the real fun, ya'll! -- */

    private static DBHelper mDbHelper;


    public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        // Use the application context, which will ensure that you
        // don't accidentally leak an Activity's context.

        if (mDbHelper == null) {
            mDbHelper = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mDbHelper;
    }


    /**
     * Constructor should be private to prevent direct instantiation.
     * Make a call to the static method "getInstance()" instead.
     */
    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TheDB, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_ParentTask_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ParentTask +
                "(" +
                parentIDColumn + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
                taskTitleColumn + " TEXT," +
                statusColumn + " BOOL," +
                dueDateColumn+ " TEXT," +
                completedColumn + " BOOL," +
                calculatedProgressColumn + " REAL" +
                ")";

        //CREATE THE PHYSICAL TABLE
        db.execSQL(CREATE_ParentTask_TABLE);

        /*String CREATE_SubTask_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SubTask +
                "(" +
                childID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," +
                foreignkey + " INT," +
                subTaskDesc + " TEXT," +
                subCompleted + " BOOL" +
                ")";

        //CREATE THE PHYSICAL TABLE
        db.execSQL(CREATE_SubTask_TABLE);*/
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            // Simplest implementation is to drop all old tables and recreate them
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ParentTask);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SubTask);

            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void insertTaskDetails(AddDo userData) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

        db.beginTransaction();

        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(parentIDColumn, userData.doParentID);
            values.put(taskTitleColumn, userData.doTaskTitle);
            values.put(statusColumn, userData.doStatus);
            values.put(dueDateColumn, userData.doDueDate);
            values.put(completedColumn, userData.doCompletedTask);
            values.put(calculatedProgressColumn, userData.doCalculatedProgress);

            db.insertOrThrow(TABLE_ParentTask, null, values);
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to add post to database");
        } finally {

            db.endTransaction();
        }


    }

   /*
   fetch all data from UserTable
    */

    public List<AddDo> getAllMainTasks() {

        List<AddDo> usersdetail = new ArrayList<>();

        String USER_DETAIL_SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_ParentTask;

        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(USER_DETAIL_SELECT_QUERY, null);

        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    AddDo userData = new AddDo();
                    userData.doParentID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(parentIDColumn));
                    userData.doTaskTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(taskTitleColumn));
                    userData.doStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(statusColumn));
                    userData.doDueDate = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dueDateColumn));
                    userData.doCompletedTask = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(completedColumn));
                    userData.doCalculatedProgress = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(calculatedProgressColumn));

                    usersdetail.add(userData);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to get posts from database");
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }

        return usersdetail;

    }

    /*
   Delete single row from ParentTask
     */
    void deleteRow(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();


        try {
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.execSQL("delete from " + TABLE_ParentTask + " where parentid ='" + parentIDColumn + "'");
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error while trying to delete task detail");
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }


    }
}
```

I was wondering if this had to do with the fact AddDo implements serializable? I could trade it off to a different XML with a standard activity, and it would work.

Any direction here would be appreciated. My professor and I have no idea why this is not wanting to behave, and neither of us used SQLite until now.

Thank you so much!

Comment: post manifest file. Seems you tried to set a class that not extends activity in your manifest file.

Comment: @MJV it's property of `styles`, with `DarkActionBar`  you will see a bar and with `NoActionBar`  there will no  `bar` , try res=>values=>styles.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddDo is not extending Activity class

Use below code extend using Activity or AppCompactActivity

```
public class AddDo extends Activity implements Serializable {
```

Comment: Thank you both, @siddhesh and Pavneet Singh, for explaining I needed to extend Activity!

Comment: with Activity it draws a blank white screen. When I extend AppCompatActivity, it gives me the title bar (but nothing else). Am I overlooking something? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Error descrption :

```
Unable to instantiate activity 
ComponentInfo{net.example.name.dotoday/net.name.example.dotoday.AddDo}:
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.example.name.dotoday.AddDo cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

mean

```
Android is unable to create an object of Activity , 
the reason is related with AddDo class 
android can't convert AddDo class to Activity because AddDo is not a child of
Activity but android need an activity parent-child relationship 
between AddDo and Activity
```

---

`Addo` is a simple class so you have to extends `Activity` or `AppCompactActivity`

```
class Addo  extends AppCompactActivity
```

and don't forget to register it in your `manifest.xml`

plus why you are using Serializable , you should create a separate class to use it as a model for your app like

```
class Data implements Serializable 
{
 public String doParentID, doTaskTitle, doStatus, doDueDate, doCompletedTask, doCalculatedProgress = "";

  public Data (){} // suitable default and parameterized constructor  

  .. fields and getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!! To answer your question specifically, I'm following a tutorial for implementing SQLite into my ToDo app, but I need the information obtained through the XML to be transferred through the serializable class. Thank you for your response. :)